# RubyGems 自体を削除したい

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ruby 環境を再構築するため、 RubyGems それ自体を一度削除したいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか？

RubyGems は `git clone` で取得し、ローカルリポジトリは残っています。

環境: Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ gem -v
2.4.5

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

$ cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0;ls
build_info  doc     gems
cache       extensions  specifications
```

---

コメントありがとうございます。入りきらないので編集します。

以下のようになっています。

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $:'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin14
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14
```

Comment: catfist さん、回答者への参考のために、`ruby -e 'puts $:'` の結果を張ってもらえますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RubyGems だけを消す、というのは面白いので、ここにまとめます。

### RubyGems をシステムから取り除く手順

1. 環境の調査
2. RubyGems ライブラリ本体を取り除く
3. gem パッケージを取り除く
4. gem コマンドを取り除く

#### 1. 環境の調査

以下の2つのコマンドで最初に概観をつかんでおきます。  
( **RubyGems を消す前に、必ず行ってください。** )

```bsh
$ ruby -e 'puts $:'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin14
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin14
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14

$ gem env
...
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
 ...
```

#### 2. RubyGems ライブラリ本体を取り除く

- gemconfigure.rb
- gauntlet_rubygem.rc
- rubygems.rb
- ubygems.rb
- rubygems

があれば、site ディレクトリから取り除きます。

```bsh
$ cd /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0
$ ls -la
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel    238  2 17  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel    136 11  4  2013 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1425  2 17  2014 gauntlet_rubygems.rb
drwxr-xr-x  70 root  wheel   2380  2 17  2014 rubygems
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  31694  2 17  2014 rubygems.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    268  2 17  2014 ubygems.rb
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     68  8 25  2013 universal-darwin13

$ rm -r gauntlet_rubygems.rb rubygems.rb ubygems.rb rubygems
```

※ ディレクトリは、 Linux であれば `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1`などとなっているでしょう。

#### 3. gem パッケージ等を取り除く

今回 `gem uninstall` コマンドを**使わない**でもいいので、　gems パッケージの入っているディレクトリを直接削除しましょう。一番楽しい所です。まず、 `gem env` で得られた、 `GEM PATHS` の項目を見ます。

```bsh
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

次に、一応、中身になにが入っているかを見てから消してゆきます。　（何があっても消しますが）

```bsh
$ ls -la /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
$ rm -r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0

$ ls -la /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
$ rm -r /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0

$ ls -la /Users/MY_USER_NAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
$ rm -r /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.
```

ちなみに Linux 環境だと以下のようになるでしょう

```bsh
$ ls -la /home/higon/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
$ rm -r /home/higon/.gem/ruby/1.9.1

$ ls -la /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1
$ rm -r /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1
```

※ `.gems` や `gems` ディレクトリが空になったならば、消しても良いです。

#### 4. gem コマンドを取り除く

gem コマンドの調査

```bsh
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ ls -la /usr/bin/gem*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  596  6 12  2014 /usr/bin/gem
```

シンボリックリンクで、 gem1.8 とか gem1.9.1 にリンクされていることもありますので、このような確認が必要です。(windows 環境であれば、 `gems.bat` も取り除いてください。)

gem コマンドの削除

```bsh
$ rm -r /usr/bin/gem
```

参考: [rubygems/Rakefile](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/Rakefile)

Comment: インストール先を調査し、手動で削除するという流れになるのですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: はい、残念ながら。RubyGems が何者なのかを知るにはいい機会だと思ったので、これを機会にまとめさせてもらいました。

Answer (score 5):

ruby環境を再構築されたい理由が分かりかねますが、現在もrubyが動作する状態なのであれば、rubyの環境構築は[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)を利用されたほうが便利です。

rbenvを使うと1台のMacに複数のバージョンのRubyをインストールして切り替えながら使えるようになりますし、この仕組みでインストールされたRuby環境であればインストール／アンインストールが手軽にでき、Macにもともと入っているRubyをアップデートしたりする必要はほとんどなくなるでしょう。

rbenvはhomebrewを使ってインストールするのが一番簡単です。
こちらの記事が参考になるかと思います。

http://dev.classmethod.jp/server-side/language/build-ruby-environment-by-rbenv/

Comment: 現在のRuby環境でRubygemのインストールに失敗するため、初期化した環境で試そうと思いました。

Rubyの管理自体もrbenvに移行しようとは思っているのですが、プリインストールのRuby環境上にインストールされたRubygem本体を放置したまま、rbenvでインストールするRuby上にRubygem本体をさらにインストールしても問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: `rbenv`はGemをシステムインストールのRubyとは別に管理するため、プリインストールされているRubyのgemが原因でエラーの原因となる確率は非常に低いです。

Answer (score 1):

コメント追加したかったのですが貢献度が足りずコメント出来なかったので回答にさせて頂きます。

Rubygems を本当に新しくする必要があるのかどうか、そこが一番の疑問です。

> 現在のRuby環境でRubygemのインストールに失敗する

の意味合いをもう少し確認したいです。
例えば Ruby on Rails をインストールするために `gem install rails` するとエラーが出る、ということでしょうか。 Mac のプリインストールされている Ruby は root 管理下なので gem をインストールするためには `sudo gem install rails` と `sudo` する必要があります。

> rben‌​vでインストール

rbenv でインストールされる Ruby にも、もちろん Rubygems が入っています。 rbenv で選択したその Ruby の環境は、プリインストール環境側の Rubygems を無視しますので、放置したままの状況で問題ないと思います。
また、いま確認しましたが

```
$ rbenv global 2.2.0 
$ gem -v
2.4.5
```

となっており、 Ruby 2.2.0であれば Rubygems も最新になっています。

Comment: インストールに失敗したのは単にsudoが足りないせいでした。失礼いたしました。
しかしながら他の問題もありまして、具体的にはvmailなどの一部gemが動きません。
そのため、rbenvで再構築してみます。